# Assign Tasks based on roles and departments

Tags: php, mysql, rbac

I am trying to get a list of users who have ability to assign tasks to other users based on their roles and department.

I am using RBAC for general access control but I need a way where each role has ability to assign task to other users based on their departments.
below are the tables I am using.

1. users
2. roles
3. role_user
4. departments
5. department_users

Check fiddle below for full structure

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/265ff0/2

```
SELECT ru.user_id
     , du.department_id
     , ru.role_id
  FROM role_user ru
  JOIN department_user du
    on du.user_id = ru.user_id 
  JOIN allowed_assign aa
    on ru.role_id = aa.allowed_role 
 WHERE ru.role_id = 4
```

I tried creating a 6th table called allowed_assign where i have role_id, department_id and allowed_roleid but no luck.

Please advice on best way to handle this issue.

thanks in advance.

Comment: ok i have tried
    `SELECT role_user.user_id as 'user_id', 
    department_user.department_id as 'department_id', role_user.role_id 
    as 'role_id' FROM role_user JOIN department_user on 
    department_user.user_id=role_user.user_id JOIN allowed_assign on 
    role_user.role_id=allowed_assign.allowed_role WHERE 
    role_user.role_id=4`

but i am able to get only allowed role and if allowed role is 0 all roles must be allowed. any ideas?

Comment: I have updated the post with your SQL.

Comment: Look into ABAC (attribute based) or open policy engine